# How to use 'map' to map realm collection change notifications to UITableview sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

Realm Collection Notifications works fine while mapping with UITableView rows using 'map'. How do i achieve the same by mapping it to UITableView sections.

For rows I follow the below code:

```
notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
  guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
  switch changes {
  case .Initial:
    tableView.reloadData()
    break
  case .Update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(modifications.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    break
  case .Error(let error):
    // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
    fatalError("\(error)")
    break
  }
}
```

For sections, I work with:

```
tableview.beginUpdates()
                    for insertIndex in insertions {
                        tableview.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: insertIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    }
                    for deleteIndex in deletions {
                        tableview.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: deleteIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    }
                    for reloadIndex in modifications {
                        tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: reloadIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    }
                    tableview.endUpdates()
```

And this works.

But I want to know about 'map' and how to use it to map sections.

```
 tableView.insertSections(insertions.map { NSIndexSet(index: $0) }, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

And also,

```
tableview.insertSections(insertions.map({ (index) -> NSIndexSet in
                        NSIndexSet(index: index)
                    }), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

But, both gives me the same error

> 'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type 'NSIndexSet'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns a new collection by replacing each of the original collection elements with a mapped version of that same element.  In other words:

```
insertions.map { ...}
```

returns an array, while `tableView.insertSections` expects a single NSIndexSet argument.

The closest you're going to get is:

```
for indexSet in insertions.map { NSIndexSet(index: $0) } {
    tableView.insertSections(indexSet, ...)
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a NSIndexSet that's a conjunction of the individual elements using `reduce`, something like:

```
tableView.insertSections(insertions.reduce(NSMutableIndexSet()) {
    $0.addIndex($1)
    return $0
}, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

But that really seems to be obscuring the code rather than clarifying it.

Comment: Thank you. Now i get what map function is.